# Evaluating whether the contents of a textbox is nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to evaluate the contents of a ASP Label to see whether it is null / nothing, and then filling another label with an error message.

Here is the evaluation (EDIT: **Updated to include working code**):

> ```
> Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>     If String.IsNullOrEmpty(lb_showcoordinates.Text) Then
>         nocoordinatesmessage.Text = "Please validate your meeting location above using the <b>Validate Address</b> button"
>         Console.WriteLine("okay")
>     Return
>     End If
>     Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
>     conn.Open()
>     Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Events (EventTitle, EventDescription, EventDate,EventCategory, CreatedBy, StreetAddress, Town, Country, Coordinates) VALUES (@f1,@f2,@f3,@f4,@f5,@f6,@f7,@f8,@f9)", conn)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", tb_eventtitle.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", tb_eventdescription.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", DateTime.ParseExact(tb_eventdate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", dd_eventcategory.SelectedIndex + 1)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f5", User.Identity.Name)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f6", txtStreetAddress.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f7", txtSuburb.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f8", txtCountry.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f9", lb_showcoordinates.Text)
>     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
>     conn.Close()
>     Response.Redirect("calendar.aspx")
> End Sub
> ```

Unfortunately I am not getting the desired results; the contents of my label have been left empty (on purpose) so I was wondering what I am doing wrong? What is the correct expression in VB.NET to evaluate whether the contents of a textbox/label/any other text based asp control (i.e. .Text) is empty?

Here is my debug process screenshot:

[image: nothing or maybe not?]

As you can see the contents of the lb_showcoordinates.Text is empty (or at least "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `String.IsNullOrEmtpy`:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(lb_showcoordinates.Text) Then
    lb_nocoordinatesmessage.Text = "Please validate your meeting location above using the <b>Validate Address</b> button"
    Console.WriteLine("okay")
End If
```

When a `textbox` is empty its contents are an empty string, so comparing to `Nothing` won't work.

Comment: I implemented this but it still evaluated it as false, meaning lb_nocoordinatesmessage did not display the message and the insert into the database took place. I have included my full sub routine so you can get any idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: You need to add a `Return` before `End If`. In the debugger, does it go inside the If statement?

Comment: Sorry yes I literally just realised what I was doing wrong! Return fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a requiredfieldvalidator which will require the user to enter the field and then you know it's filled in by the time the button click is called.